# Out of Memory on ViewPager which in turn contains another ViewPager as a child

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, android-volley

I am creating an application which contains a ViewPager with five views. I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for the five tabs. Each tab contains view inflated via `Fragment`.

In all those five tabs there are several number of images coming from server and some additional data
For ex - tab one contains seven images with some supporting related text data , means by that tab contains seven views which I am switching the view using `PagerAdapter`  and all that seven images are switching by swipe gesture using a `ViewPager` for each view(image + text).

And there are four other similar tabs also.

When I open this screen the heap memory is drastically increasing previously I was using

1. Volley library for Image Caching since there are frequent use of images. But when I analysed the .hprof file in Memory Analyser Tool , I found the "ImageLoader" is occupying very much amount of memory
2. Using `android:largeGeap="true"` in android manifest tag  , which is    definitely not the right approach

But even then `ImageLoader` is increasing drastically. So I removed the `ImageCaching` from that page and store the images in internal storage and recovered them when needed again without downloading from the server.

I failed to manage the heap memory resulting in OutOfMemory Exception and crash and unresponsiveness.

Is there is any problem in (`ViewPager`) OR (`Viewager` inside `ViewPager`) or there is any other issue resulting in memory leak.

Comment: I would not put a ViewPager inside another ViewPager. Nested views which scroll on the same axis are (a) visually confusing and (b) may not behave correctly (because the system may decide one of them should process a particular sequence of touch events when you actually expected the other one to handle them). Perhaps consider an alternative navigation mechanism like a NavigationDrawer. As for memory issues, `android:largeHeap="true"` doesn't fix your problems, it only masks them. Perhaps this guide will help: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted your code, but keep in mind that every device out there will have different memory constraints and you should be sure you are downsampling your images to an acceptable size.

hope this helps:  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html